# Puzzled about CUDA "Warp Out-of-range Address" error

Tags: cuda, gpu

I implemented a numerical algorithm on GPU with CUDA. At first, I set the gridDim<32, 1, 1> and blockDim<1, 1, 1>, the program threw out an "Warp Out-of-range Address" error at a line with where only some basic arithmetic operations involved (I know that the reported location of this error is not accurate, and I have tried to find out the accurate position of this error by commenting and rule out search, but it seems this error comes from nowhere!).

And if I change the combination of gridDim<32, 1, 1> and blockDim to <32, 1, 1>, the program works quite fine! And I have also tried the combination of gridDim<1, 1, 1> and blockdim<1, 1, 1>, the program also work fine. Can anyone tell me some possible reasons for this?

---

UPDATE: I found my program has the possibility to crash unless only one thread is launched. And the crash is unpredictable. 
And if I launched multiple threads, but only let one thread to execute the kernel function, for example:

```
__global__ kernel<<<32, 32>>>{
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tid != XXX)
        return;
    else{
        ...
    }

}
```

I found that only when XXX is 0 can my program guarantee to run successfully. I want to know the reason. Is there any difference among the threads to execute the kernel function?

Comment: `__global__ kernel<<<32, 32>>>{`

This is not valid syntax.  Kernel declarations use the `__global__` specifier, but the execution configuration(`<<<>>>`) should only be used on kernel invocation, that is when you call the kernel from your host code.

Please read the CUDA programming guide or look at some samples.

Comment: If you are going to show some code, show the __actual__ code you are using. What you have shown is uncompilable nonsense and is completely unhelpful for getting and answer to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for all of the advices. But my program has several thousands lines of codes and some details has nothing to do with the problem. I just want to make the problem easier to be understood by ruling out the unimportant details. Anyhow, I will remember your advices and try to made my problems both meaningful and easy to understood. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you saying you have a kernel with several thousands of lines of code? If so, can't you just starting your debugging by commenting blocks of it out until your isolate the code causing the error?

Comment: @talonmies Yes, with all the subroutines, the amount of codes of my kernel is huge. I have tried, however, I found the error is difficult to ascertain. cuda-gdb crashed a line of code, and I commented the crashed code, cuda-gdb crashed at another line. And if I add some garbage codes in front of that line, the location of the error changed. And EVEN, if I print some words in the other place, the location changes too! I am frustrated. I thought it might be the error of memory management because I use too much scattered arrays with cudaMalloc(). But I can not find a way to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating tid wrong.

tid is calculated as:

int tid = **blockIdx.x** * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. I made a spelling mistake here.

Comment: @talonmies I am sorry, but I implemented right in my program code. Still searching for the bug.